# Building a widget (HTML/CSS) -- table or divs?

Tags: html, css, html-table

(See widget image below for structure and possible content). So here's the deal: in the application I'm working on, there is a fixed-size widget with variable content. The content has between 3 and 5 containers of 'content' that vary depending on where and when the widget is displayed. The widget itself, however, is always the same size.

The content within each 'container' is always vertically and horizontally aligned to the center. The combinations (see image below) are:

- The Status contianer is always there (container 1)
- The 2nd 'row' has either 1 or two containers; if one, it spans whole width; if two, each is 1/2 of the total
- The 3rd row is the same as the 2nd row, with the addition/change that it can also be empty

Now--there are 2 ways to approach this problem, as I see it: Divs and Table.

If a div, it would be something like:

```
<div outer container>
 <div container 1></div>
 <div container 2>
  <div container 2a></div>
  <div container 2b></div>
 </div> end container 2
 <div container 3>
  <div container 3a></div>
  <div container 3b></div>
 </div> end container 3
</div> end outer container
```

If it's a table, it would be:

```
<table>
 <tr colspan=2><td>Container 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Container 2a</td><td>Container 2b</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Container 3a</td><td>Container 3b</td></tr>
</table>
```

And if the 2nd or 3rd container were only one 'column', apply the colspan appropriately.

It seems to me like the Tables approach is simpler, especially when it comes to horizontal and vertical object alignment, but I want to check with others, as I know tables tend to be verboten. I actually believe a table is appropriate here, though, because it is actually displaying tabular data as its content!

Thoughts?

[Architecture of Widget http://www.5sn1.com/images/quantity_widget.png](http://www.5sn1.com/images/quantity_widget.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using tables for layout is generally frowned upon, but there's no real reason not to use them. As you said, it does make it easier and more logical.

All in all, you really should just go with whichever works for you.

Comment: Yeah...it's tricky because I am displaying tabular data--3 rows, 1 or two columns of data--but visually of course it doesn't look like a table as much as a widget that one would normally build using divs (and, in fact, the previous developer did build using DIV widgets--but it's causing issues).

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against *going with whatever works for you*. Yes, in the short term it would be the easiest method, however, maintaining/updating the layout later on may become more difficult. I would say don't only think of the 'now', but think about the expansion or say in future if another developer would need to take over the work.

Use what works *for the site/app*. If it is most important that the site UI is 100% picture perfect, or 100% cross browser compatible, or 100% validating code. Sadly, it is usually not possible to have all three situations. Thus, use what works for the site and is maintainable.

Personally I would use a table in displaying tabular data instead of juggling around DIVs *if it made sense to do so*.

Comment: Cross-Browser and validating code are less important, 100% picture perfect is most important. The environment is fixed in terms of width/height, browser used, etc. So chrome on windows XP and/or Windows 7 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion either methods are fine, although if you're aiming for those widgets to be cross-browser, you'll have less headaches using tables, like in vertical alignment like you mentioned. Just keep in mind that tables for layout is bad in most cases, but even i use them when the boss calls IE 7/8 to the table.

I don't think that example is considered tabular data, generally its something like a datagrid.

Anyways, like Kolink said, its up to you, just use the method that works for you.

Comment: IE9 and up, I believe. We have a fixed environment for usage.